# Gradient descent from mathematical ideation for sum of squared errors

Tags: python, machine-learning, matrix-multiplication, gradient-descent

I have the following gradient descent algorithm that I derived mathematically for sum of squared errors. However, when I implement it, the losses increase as shown below. I'm trying to understand the error but can't seem to find the mathematical fallacy as the dimensions and derivation line up, so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

I also used a randomly generated dataset as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

testing = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
testing.insert(0, 'W_o', 1) # W initial 
testing.insert(-1, 'Y', np.random.randint(0,4,size=(100, 1))) #target
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def grad_descent_SSE(X,y,T,lr):
  
  # Shape of dataset
  m,n = X.shape

  #Initialize parameters
  W = np.zeros(n)
  # W = OLS[0]

  # Track loss over time
  f = np.zeros(T)

  for i in range(T):

    # Loss for the current parameter vector W
    f[i] = 0.5*np.linalg.norm(X.dot(W) - y)**2

    # Compute steepest ascent at f(W)
    W_update = np.matmul(X.T,np.matmul(X,W)-y)
    # W_update = np.transpose(X).dot(X.dot(W) - y)

    # Calculating the updated weights 
    W = W - lr * W_update

  return W,f, plt.plot(f,'b-o')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer :** You are probably using a larger learning rate. Try reducing the learning rate.

**Long Answer :** Let's take 20 random samples, each having a dimension of 5. Then our X will have the dimension of (20,5). Let's assume `W_t` is the true weight we are aiming to reach. If we ignore the bias, then the linear equation becomes `y = W_t*X`.

```
n = 5
m = 20 
X = np.random.random((m,n))
W_t = np.random.random(n)
y = np.matmul(X,W_t)
```

If I use your function with `T=10` and `lr=10`

```
grad_descent_SSE(X,y,10,10)
```

I get a graph similar as you.

[image]

When I reduce the learning rate to 0.01 (`lr=0.01`), the gradient is descending.

[image]

Comment: Okay. I played with learning rates. Same plot as above (increasing loss but with lr=10 (1e99), lr=0 (0), lr =0.001 (1e27) and lr=0.00001(1e-10)

Comment: @ablam to further explain the learning rate is how much the weights will change so if you have a large learning rate the numbers will jump around by crazy amounts. So, setting the learning rate to a lower amount will make it so it won't jump around as much. I recommend with every SGD algorithm start the learning rate with `0.1`

Comment: I see. Okay, I will play with it more to find the best fit. I'm seeing that now too with a couple of examples. Thank you.